# How to programmatically terminate io.scalac.amqp.Connection from reactive-rabbit library

Tags: scala, rabbitmq, reactive-programming, akka-stream

I am using akka streams in combination with the reactive-rabbit library to build a script that pushes some information to a exchange on my local rabbitmq server.

Once the information is pushed to the queue, I'd like the program to close by itself. However the `Connection` keeps the program alive and I can't find any methods on `Connection` or other examples of how to kill it. Inevitably I have to manually kill the process.

My code looks something like this:

```
package prototype

import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.FlowMaterializer
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{Sink, Source}
import akka.util.ByteString
import io.scalac.amqp.{Message, Connection}

object PopulateTodoQueue extends App {
  val connection = Connection()

  val message = Message(ByteString("message"))

  val source = Source(List(message))
  val sink = Sink(connection.publishDirectly(queue = "todo"))

  implicit val actorSystem = ActorSystem()
  implicit val materializer = FlowMaterializer()

  (source to sink).run()

  // Quick hack to wait long enough for the message to send
  Thread.sleep(1000)
  actorSystem.shutdown()
}
```

This is a snippet from my build.sbt library dependencies:

```
"com.typesafe.akka"          %%  "akka-actor"               % "2.3.7",
"com.typesafe.akka"          %%  "akka-stream-experimental" % "0.11",
"io.scalac"                  %%  "reactive-rabbit"          % "0.2.1",
```

Is there a better pattern for these one off tasks - like a temporary connection that you pass a callback to? All the use cases in examples I've seen are for long running clients which run until the user explicitly kills them.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: +1, I'm currently wondering about the same thing, though my use-case is the other way around, using reactive-rabbit to subscribe...

Comment: @Tycho This question has sat here for a long time so I don't think you'll get an answer. I don't know that they even maintain the library any more. I ended up just going back to the simple java driver and writing a small wrapper for it to abstract over the blocking nature of the consumer. You could email the company (http://www.scalac.io/). I've hit this kind of thing a lot with scala drivers - they're often overly complex or not maintained/supported well.

Answer (score 0):

there is shutdown method in connection trait

```
/** Shutdowns underlying connection.
    * Publishers and subscribers are terminated and notified via `onError`.
    * This method waits for all close operations to complete. */
  def shutdown(): Future[Unit]
```

you can call this way

```
connection.shutdown()
```